# Why does S need to be non-empty for $F^S$ to be a Vector Space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, definition

In the book "Linear algebra done Right" p.14 the example problem asks to prove that if S is non-empty then $F^S$ is a vector space. Addition is defined as $(f+g)(x) = f(x) + g(x)$ and scalar multiplication is defined as $(af)(x) = a*f(x)$ for all $a \in F$ and  $f,g \in F^S$

What if S is empty? It seems to me that $F^S$ could still be a vector space. Do we need to change the definitions of addition and scalar multiplication to make this work?

If we change the definitions of addition and multiplication I think we can make it work as follows:

Suppose S is empty. Then there is only one function $f:S \rightarrow F$, namely the empty function $\varnothing$. Define vector addition as $u + v = \varnothing$ for all $u,v \in F^{\varnothing}$. Then define scalar multiplication as $av = \varnothing$. Are these definitions okay? I am sorry to use $\varnothing$ for both the empty set and the empty function (I couldn't find any other symbol commonly used for the empty function).

With these definitions it seems to me that $F^{\varnothing}$ is commutative and associative. The additive identity could be the empty function, making the additive inverse also the empty function. The multiplicative identity works since 1 multiplied by the empty function is defined as the empty function. I believe the distributive properties hold as well. Does this work?

Could $F^S$ be a vector space with the usual definitions of addition $(f+g)(x) = f(x) + g(x)$ and scalar multiplication $(af)(x) = a*f(x)$ for all $a \in F$ and  $f,g \in F^S$. Maybe I do not understand the empty function enough to be able to tell...

Please advise

Comment: You are correct that your definition makes $F^\varnothing$ into an $F$-vector space, namely one isomorphic to the trivial one $\{0\}$. The usual definition also gives the same result, if stated correctly (say, $f+g$ is the unique function from $S$ to $F$ s.t. $(f+g)(x) = f(x)+g(x)$ for all $x \in S$ and $af$ is the unique function from $S$ to $F$ s.t. $(af)(x) = a \cdot f(x)$ for all $x \in S$ would work.)

Comment: The empty set is not a vector space.   A vector space contains always a zero element.   But if $S=\emptyset $, then $F^S=\emptyset $ as well.

Comment: @trivial: if you follow the usual conventions $F^\emptyset$ is not the empty set: it comprises the empty set viewed as the only possible function from the empty set to $F$.

Answer (score 3):

Your understanding is quite right. $F^\emptyset$ comprises a single element that we can call $0$ and take as the unique element of a zero-dimensional vector space over $F$. I suspect the authors of "Linear algebra done right" just didn't want to distract their readers into worrying about this special case: you quite rightly noted the special case and drew the correct conclusion.

Comment: To the downvoter: why don't you back your criticisms up with comments? As far as I can see, there is nothing techically wrong with my answer and it does address the OP's concern. My answer reinforces my comment that has received 5 upvotes. Is it possible that there is something wrong with your thinking?

Comment: The OP's question suggests that if that if the author was aiming not to distract readers about the special case, they didn't quite succeed!